# Possessive s, apostrophe on end or not?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

I am writing a project for college about smart phones.

Which would you say is correct in a possessive context?

> Windows Phone's applications

or

> Windows Phone' applications

My thoughts say the top is correct as *Phone* does not end in an S, but it just sounds horrible and wrong. The bottom one sounds correct but in my head is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Both your instincts are correct. Applications are more often referred to with [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) than genitives when describing types, so the second version, but without the apostrophe, would be better: “Windows Phone applications”. Just like ‘Apple applications’, ‘Java applications’, ‘Windows applications’, etc. No genitive at all.

Comment: Try ell.stackexchange.com for simpler questions.

Comment: A Windows Phone's applications would all be Windows Phone applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your source of confusion is apparently in assuming that every time you put two nouns together, one of them must be a possessive, so you're fretting about where to put an apostrophe when there's simply no need for one in the first place.

Just as in "truck driver", "game designer", "world war" etc, what you have is simply a compound consisting of two nouns. So similarly, you can simply write "Windows Phone applications" as your intuition dictates, but there's no need for an apostrophe.

Comment: +1 This could have been asked on ELL though.